# What is the connection between the maximum time-value in seconds, number of samples N and the sampling frequency fs in Hz?

Tags: sampling

I am working with the following:

> The script `signalsim` simulates one realization of a Gaussian stationary harmonic process according to
>
> $$x(n) = A_1 \cos (2 \pi \frac{f_1}{f s} n + \phi_1) + A_2 \cos (2 \pi \frac{f_2}{f s} n + \phi_2), \quad n = 0 \ldots N - 1,$$
>
> with frequencies $f_k = \{10, 20\} \ \mathrm{Hz}$, number of samples $N = 500$ and sample frequency $f s = 256 \ \mathrm{Hz}$. The independent phases are $\phi_k \in Rect(0, 2 \pi)$ and the independent amplitudes are $A_k \in \text{Rayleigh}(\sigma_k)$ with parameters $\sigma_k = \{2, 2\}$.

Then I was asked the question in the title. I am not really sure what they mean by "maximum time-value".

Is it just $\frac{N-1}{f_s}$?

Answer (score 1):

You have my sympathy for having to struggle interpreting that super vague question in your title. I would answer that question with: "The maximum time index of the x(n) sequence, in terms of the number of samples N and the fs sampling frequency, is (N-1)/fs seconds."